# Spark SHA Hash Coming Back Empty

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sha256

I am trying to create a SHA256 hash of each row in a dataframe.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, concat, sha2}
val finalResultWithHash = finalResult.withColumn("ROWHASH", sha2(concat(finalResult.columns.map(col):_*), 256))
```

When I had only one column in the dataframe it seemed to be working.

Later in the code I write the dataframe as a CSV and the rowhash column is empty.
I haven't been able to find any documentation on what I am doing wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing it is by using a `foldLeft()`:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("rowsha",sha2(df.columns.foldLeft(lit(""))((x,y)=>concat(x,col(y))),256))
```

Folding will concat all columns left to right before hashing it:

```
df.withColumn("rowsha",sha2(df.columns.foldLeft(lit(""))((x,y)=>concat(x,col(y))),256)).explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [c1#10, c2#11, c3#12, c4#13, sha2(cast(concat(, c1#10, c2#11, c3#12, 4#13) as binary), 256) AS rowsha#165]
+- *(1) ...
```

However, if any of the columns in concatenation contain NULLs, the result will be also NULL. To safeguard against that you might want to use something like

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("rowsha",sha2(df.columns.foldLeft(lit(""))((x,y)=>concat(x,coalesce(col(y),lit("n/a"))),256))
```

Comment: Even with this solution I am still getting no actual hash in the dataframe. I am starting to believe that the datapoints when put all together are just too long for the sha2 function.

Comment: Are any of your columns contain NULLs by any chance? If thats the case you should change the `concat(x,col(y))` to something like `concat(x,coalesce(col(y),lit("n/a")))`.

Comment: This worked... The NULL values were the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason below code works for me for multiple columns

```
val finalResultWithHash = personDF.withColumn("ROWHASH", sha2(concat(personDF.columns.map(col): _*), 256))

+-----+-----+---+------+--------------------+
|FName|LName|Age|Gender|             ROWHASH|
+-----+-----+---+------+--------------------+
|    A|    B| 29|     M|c4ae6946a295e9d74...|
|    A|    C| 12|      |89a18fdc3ddb3c2fd...|
|    B|    D| 35|     F|ef1c89dfc765c7e1e...|
|    Q|    D| 85|      |cd91aa387a7e6a180...|
|    W|    R| 14|      |e9ff9bb78fd93a13a...|
+-----+-----+---+------+--------------------+
```

Could it be just the bracket placement mistake ...

Comment: Sorry I totally left that one bracket out when I wrote the question... I do have that in my code, however it is strange that I am getting an error and you are getting results... Maybe I have too columns or some sort of row length issue